# Upload a pdf file without the actuall upload

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Ones again I have a question which I hope to get help with.

I have a small database where I want to include information about the location of specific pdf files. This means that I am not saving the actual pdf’s just their location on a local drive.

The issue is that I don’t need to do any upload of the file since they are located where I want them to be beforehand.

My actual form code is a type="file" code with a browser button. It saves a copy of the pdfs into pdffiles map. What I want is to keep the browser button functionality but without the need of saving the files in the pdffiles map, plus that I want the saved pathway in Mysql code to be the original location of the file.

I hope you can understand what I am trying to achieve.
Thanks to you all!

---

Unfortunately, my knowledge in JavaScript is limited.
The form line I am trying to read is simple: 
Say I have a file: C:\test\Ritningsregister\pdffile1.pdf

Like I said before all I want is to store the path info of the current file into MySql without any upload/download involved. I have been trying to use pathinfo($_FILES['filename']['name'], PATHINFO_DIRNAME) but it only gives me the relative path, ie .

pathinfo($_FILES['filename']['name'], PATHINFO_BASENAME) returns pdffile1.pdf as it should.

I have also trying to use realpath($_FILES['filename']['name']) hoping it will give me the whole path information: C:\test\Ritningsregister\ … without any luck.

What I at least could establish is that when I am trying to open a pdf file whose pathway has beforehand been imputed into MySQL say: C:/test/Ritningsregister/pdffile1.pdf. The browser had no problem in opening it. 
So I really hope you can help me to solve this problem!
Best regards CaLey

Comment: Mmm, that question have no sense. Remove the `input[type=file]` element and simply put in the database the path of the file... But then, how you choose the file? There's something missing in your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[edit]

well what you could do then is use javascript to grab the value from the input-file and put that text into the value of a hidden input, and then reset the input-file so no file is uploaded. if you need help working out how to do this let me know :)

[edit]

are you just trying to process some file locations into a database ? as you can use php scripting to just read a directory's file's and then save that into a db without a form at all

Comment: I use PHP to create a Mysql database where ONE of the information I want to store is the location of pdf-files. 
I don’t want to use a simple <input type="text"> line in the form, since I don’t want to impute the pathway information by hand: for instance c:/register/file1.pdf
I would like to be able to use the “browser” button to get to the file information I need.

Comment: please see my original answer